# How to disable autocomplete on combobox in access?

Tags: ms-access, combobox, autocomplete

In MS Access I can't disable autocomplete on a combobox.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to disable the fill-in-as-you-type feature of a combo box:

1. Open a form in Design view mode
2. Select the combobox
3. Right-click on the combo-box and select Properties to open the property sheet for the combo box
4. In the AutoExpand property box, click No.

Note:

When the AutoExpand property is off, a value must be selected from the list or the whole value typed.